# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...) ignores data

Tags: php, mysql, database

i am concatenating multiple rows and columns of a table storing postal addresses using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

My table looks like this (simplified):

```
id | street  | hNumber
-----------------------
1  | streetA | 1       
-----------------------
2  | streetB | 2      
-----------------------
3  | streetC | NULL    
-----------------------
```

In some cases i need to concatenate addresse which i am doing like this: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT table.street, ' ', table.hNumber SEPARATOR ', ') as street`

This for example would give me *StreetA 1, StreetB 2* as a result which is just what i want. Sadly this method does not work for cases where for example the `hNumber` is empty, in those cases it just returns `street` as `NULL`.
For rows in which the `hNumber` table cell is empty i would like to see it just skip over the empty field and return `street` as *StreetA 1, StreetC*.

I hope someone can point me in a direction to approach this problem the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL skips any of those rows that contain a NULL value.
The short answer is to anticipate a possible NULL value for a column and prepare for it. e.g.:

`` SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `street`, ' ' , IFNULL(`hNumber`,"") SEPARATOR ', ') ``

(create empty string, if hNumber is NULL)

Comment: This is the correct answer, thank you very much sir.